# Any good (lightweight) android emulator for bug bounty purposes?

Tags: windows, android-emulator

I'm trying to do Security Research on Android Applications but I can't seem to find any good android emulators out there.

I have installed [MEMUPLAY](https://www.memuplay.com/) which worked great until I've upgraded to Android 7 and the IP address does not bridge with my WLAN adapter anymore.

Have tried using their VM Manager, installed the driver and everything and cannot get the bridged IP address to show up.

Instead of DHCP assigning the traditional IP address (192.168.X.X), instead it assigns a different format (10.0.X.X)

Have also tried to modify the VM configuration file but that did not change much. It reverts to the default again.

---

TL;DR

I need a good android 7 emulator that does not require Android Studio or hundreds of files to work. It needs to have root access, very easy file management over the Host machine and ability to bridge the connection over.

Comment: The original Android emulator does not require Android Studio. You can still download the SDK without Android Studio: https://developer.android.com/studio#command-tools. And the Emulator can be started via command-line.

Comment: What OS should it run on (from your mentioning Memuplay, I assume Windows)? And if it would be paid, what would be your price limit? While waiting for good recommendations, be welcome to take a look at my list at the end of [this page](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/emulators).

Comment: @Izzy I'm running Windows 10 latest build. I'll take a look at your list of recommendations and If one satisfies my needs I'll mark your answer as accepted.

Comment: As my "answer" was just a comment: be welcome to [answer your own question](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer) and accept it then :) Good luck!